# Collision Avoidance/Steering around moving obstacles

Tags: collision-detection

I've done a decent amount of research and I've read up on pathfinding algorithms and such, but I can't seem to find anything to do with the mentioned behaviors when moving around obstacles that also move.

My character has a circular hitbox, as do the obstacles. My character has a fixed velocity, but can also come to a full stop. My character can also change directions near instantly. Acceleration/deceleration of my character is instant. I can predict, with 100% accuracy, where the obstacles will be; I know their velocity, starting position, and ending position. Obstacles are generated by the user, move at a predetermined velocity (depending on which obstacle it is), and have a predetermined length (again, depending on the obstacle).

I want my character to path from point A to point B while moving around all the obstacles (with no collisions). Point A is where my character currently is, and point B is a user picked point which might change at any time (edit: Pathfinding itself isn't the issue; it's just local collision avoidance that I need to deal with).

Let me know if you need any more info; I don't know what is needed!

Comment: Did you read about [RVO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxzrHRIiVyk)? The implementation is freely available. There is also OpenSter which should work for this case.

Comment: I've looked at OpenSteer and RVO, but unfortunately I don't know C++ and don't know where to look or how to use it. I was hoping for something that explained the math so I could implement it myself, or something similar.

Comment: I see. Well the academic articles are there. They are not easy by any means. Learning C++ might be easier than reimplementing this.